# Pandas new column per days

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data frame:

```
user     day
A        1
A        4
B        2
B        4
```

I want to change the data frame into this:

```
user   day_1   day_2   day_3   day_4
A      1       0       0       1
B      0       1       0       1
```

So it will automatically generate day_3 even there is no user on day_3

I have tried with this code but it doesn't work

```
for index, row in grouped_user.iterrows():
    grouped_user["day_" + str(int(row.active_period))] = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with converting to strings and aggregate `max` :

```
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df.astype(str), columns=['day']).groupby('user', as_index=False).max()
print (df1)
  user  day_1  day_2  day_4
0    A      1      0      1
1    B      0      1      1
```

If is necessary add missing days convert `user` to index, use `get_dummies` with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for add all possible days to columns:

```
days = [f'day_{x}' for x in range(df['day'].min(), df['day'].max() + 1)]
df1 = (pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('user').astype(str))
         .max(level=0)
         .reindex(columns=days, fill_value=0)
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
  user  day_1  day_2  day_3  day_4
0    A      1      0      0      1
1    B      0      1      0      1
```

Another solution with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and [`DataFrame.clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html):

```
df1 = (pd.crosstab(df['user'], df['day'])
         .clip(upper=1)
         .reindex(range(df['day'].min(), df['day'].max()+1), fill_value=0, axis=1)
         .add_prefix('day_')
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
  user  day_1  day_2  day_3  day_4
0    A      1      0      0      1
1    B      0      1      0      1
```

Comment: it's error KeyError: "None of [Index(['day'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]" and I need the day_3

Comment: @OctavianWR You either use the first solution or the second. You shouldn't combine both as jezrael has named the solution as df as well which overwrites the original df

Comment: @jezrael oops my bad, I haven't changed the df name. It's worked but I need the day_3

Comment: @jezrael, I don't know why the code is not working on the second try. the result is all 0. There is no problem in the first try and I thought I can accept two answer

Comment: @jezrael I don't think so. I have included it

Comment: @OctavianWR - Added new solution.

Comment: @OctavianWR - Super ;)

Comment: @jezrael. Thank you. anyway, can you help me with this too? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58811617/create-week-label-from-multiple-days-columns) thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can use the function [`pivot_table()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df.assign(vals=1).\
pivot_table(index='user', columns='day', values='vals', fill_value=0).\
reindex(range(df['day'].min(), df['day'].max()+1), fill_value=0, axis=1).\
add_prefix('day_')
```

Result:

```
day   day_1  day_2  day_3  day_4
user                            
A         1      0      0      1
B         0      1      0      1
```