# Create week label from multiple days columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have this pandas data frame:

```
user   join_date    days_0    days_1   ...   days_n
A      10-08-2019   1         1        ...   0
B      11-08-2019   0         1        ...   1
                       ...
Z      30-19-2019   1         1        ...   1
```

I want to add multiple columns from days column condition. So I want to aggregate the column with sum. This is data frame that I expected:

```
user   join_date    days_0    days_1   ...   days_n   week_1   week_2   ...   week_n
A      10-08-2019   1         1        ...   0        2        3              1
B      11-08-2019   0         1        ...   1        1        0              2
                       ...
Z      30-19-2019   1         1        ...   1        5        1              5
```

Number of days and week are dynamic and always updated

Comment: So you need aggregate each 7 days to one week?

Comment: @jezrael yeah 0-6 is 1 week

Comment: ok, give me some time for solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
np.random.seed(123)

#sample data
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'user': list('ABZ'),
                   'join_date':['10-08-2019','11-08-2019','30-19-2019']})  


df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0,1], size=(3, 20))).add_prefix('days_')  

df = df1.join(df2)
print (df)
  user   join_date  days_0  days_1  days_2  days_3  days_4  days_5  days_6  \
0    A  10-08-2019       0       1       0       0       0       0       0   
1    B  11-08-2019       0       0       1       1       1       0       1   
2    Z  30-19-2019       0       1       0       1       1       1       0   

   days_7  ...  days_10  days_11  days_12  days_13  days_14  days_15  days_16  \
0       1  ...        1        1        0        1        0        1        0   
1       0  ...        0        1        1        1        0        0        1   
2       0  ...        1        1        0        0        1        0        1   

   days_17  days_18  days_19  
0        1        1        0  
1        0        0        1  
2        0        0        1  

[3 rows x 22 columns]
```

You can filter columns with `days` by [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
print (df.filter(like='days_'))
   days_0  days_1  days_2  days_3  days_4  days_5  days_6  days_7  days_8  \
0       0       1       0       0       0       0       0       1       1   
1       0       0       1       1       1       0       1       0       0   
2       0       1       0       1       1       1       0       0       0   

   days_9  days_10  days_11  days_12  days_13  days_14  days_15  days_16  \
0       0        1        1        0        1        0        1        0   
1       0        0        1        1        1        0        0        1   
2       0        1        1        0        0        1        0        1   

   days_17  days_18  days_19  
0        1        1        0  
1        0        0        1  
2        0        0        1
```

Then groupby with lambda function for convert number after `_` to integer and use integers division for groups by each 7 columns (`// 6` because python counts from `0`) with aggregation `sum`:

```
df3 = (df.filter(like='days_')
         .groupby(lambda x: int(x.split('_')[1]) // 6, axis=1)
         .sum()
         .add_prefix('week_'))  
print (df3)
   week_0  week_1  week_2  week_3
0       1       4       3       1
1       3       2       3       1
2       4       2       2       1
```

Last join to original:

```
df = df.join(df3)
print (df)
  user   join_date  days_0  days_1  days_2  days_3  days_4  days_5  days_6  \
0    A  10-08-2019       0       1       0       0       0       0       0   
1    B  11-08-2019       0       0       1       1       1       0       1   
2    Z  30-19-2019       0       1       0       1       1       1       0   

   days_7  ...  days_14  days_15  days_16  days_17  days_18  days_19  week_0  \
0       1  ...        0        1        0        1        1        0       1   
1       0  ...        0        0        1        0        0        1       3   
2       0  ...        1        0        1        0        0        1       4   

   week_1  week_2  week_3  
0       4       3       1  
1       2       3       1  
2       2       2       1  

[3 rows x 26 columns]
```

Comment: I think the correct group by is // by 7, not 6. 'groupby(lambda x: int(x.split('_')[1]) // 7, axis=1)'

Comment: It's for my dataset. I don't know what is the difference of my dataset with your dataset

Comment: @OctavianWR - If need `//7` I think difference is first day is 1, not 0 like in sample data.

Comment: No, My first day is day_0